# Is it better to use regular expressions to match on content or on delimiter?

Tags: java, regex

For a concrete example, I want to break a text document into sentences. I'm considering using the follow regular expressions (still might need tweaking):

- `[!?][\s]*|[.\n][!?\s]+[.!?\s]*` which matches on punctuation/whitespace (stuff between sentences - delimiters)
- `(.|\n)*?([!?.]\s+|[\n]{2,}|$)`: which captures any string of characters followed by punctuation or newline (full sentences - the content I want itself)

Generally, which of these methods are preferred? In my specific context, I'd like to keep track of the begin and end indices of each sentence, so I can't do something as simple as [String#split](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)).

Thanks.

Comment: Can you show sample input and desired output text.

Comment: I think that none of these methods is generally prefered, everything depends on task and conditions in which it will work. And sometimes I think it just doeasn't metter,

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you intend to use vanilla `Pattern` and `Matcher` processing, the first regex will usually be capturing much, much fewer characters (ending punctuation and some whitespace characters at most) and as such should be the fastest. This can make a difference if you're parsing a very huge document.

However, it might be clumsier to extract start and end indexes for each sentence, because you'll need information from two consecutive matches to be able to delimit a whole sentence. The second regex directly maps sentences to individual matches and enables the simplest code.

So no free lunch here. Both will get the job done, although you can probably make them more robust depending on the type of document you're targeting. In particular, beware of unexpected punctuation characters in the middle of sentences, as in :

> ... the "?" character can be used to...